# How to get connections string from .exe files. Is there any possibility?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, connection-string

I have an `.exe` file and it is working properly. It connects to a SQL Server 2012 database. I need to know the authentication to the database. Is there any way to do this? Can I get the connection string from `.exe` file some way?

Comment: If it's a non-obfuscated .NET Framework .exe: Decompile it.

Answer (score 3):

If your .net application is not obfuscated (protected against decompilation) you can get it's c# source by decompiling it with a tool like Resharper from JetBrains (contains assembly explorer tool) or free tool called ILSpy http://ilspy.net/.

I'd just add up that if it is not a tool written by you or your company, decompiling it might be a violation of a license agreement of this application.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fully standalone .exe, there are a couple of options:

1. Various configuration files that include the connection details may be compressed / merged into the executable, and can be extracted by various means.
2. The connection details are hard coded into the C# code, which can then be decompiled.

For decompilation, try [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). For simple extraction, you can try [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can try to decompile your executable (assembly) using [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (it is free).

Just drag and drop your file into the application, it might ask you for some dependencies. Skip them if they do not seem related to your application and you will be able to see the decompiled code.